# Why not an answer flag declined?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I raised a flag, not a answer (link only answer) for [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1228774/843638) answer.

Answer only provide youtube tutorial link . But flag is declined with message:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical
>   inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

What I am missing here.

Screenshot in case answer is deleted.

[image]

Comment: Not sure why this flag got declined tho, all I can say is that I casted the last delete vote on this answer, so it is gone now.

Comment: I'm not sure why this flag got declined either. I cast the first delete vote on this answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems to have been a mistake, I think. I would agree with your flag. As others pointed out, it got deleted via community vote now anyway.

Thanks for reporting and sorry for the confusion and inconvenience.

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes I don't feel self-confident enough to flag an answer without commenting below it to explain the reason why I flagged it to other reviewers, but I think it's safe to flag link-only answers like this one as "not an answer" without commenting. I was also asked by a moderator to stop using custom flags for link-only answers and use "not an answer" as the reason to flag link-only answers instead.